# Cannot get my video-background to stay the same when resizing screen

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

I'm new at CSS. I'm testing out video backgrounds at the moment and I'm unable to have the video background stay the same size when I resize my screen smaller or open my dev tools. The background becomes smaller whenever I make my screen smaller.

[This is what the background looks like when the screen is smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlLcl.jpg)

Can anyone help me figure out how to make my video background responsive and make it stay the same size no matter the size of the screen, please?

This is the styling I currently have for my video background:

```
    video {
      z-index: -1000;
      left: 50%;
      max-width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .showcase {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
```

I do not have any styling for my body. And my video tag sits inside showcase tag.

This is how my video background is being rendered:

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <>
      <section id="showcase">
        <video src="clouds.mp4" muted loop autoPlay></video>
        <QuoteBox />
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don’t think I understand what is meant by ‘stay the same size’. Different devices and viewports have different aspect ratios. Do you want the whole video always to be in view, in which case it will show blank margins either at the top/bottom or the sides or do you want it to cover the whole screen in which case it will be cropped?

Comment: @AHaworth If you take a look at my screen shot, its my desktop screen, when I make my desktop screen smaller, (For example, open up my dev tools) The background video, becomes smaller, leaving white space in my app. How can I make it stay the same as it looks when my desktop screen is full?

Comment: Could you confirm that you want all the video to be in view? Or the alternative is to have it filling the screen but cropped. Which do you want?

Comment: @AHaworth all the video in the view. The video background has to take up the entire page of the website, no white spaces pls!

Comment: If you have no white space then the video cannot be fully  in view unless the viewport aspect ratio is the same as the video's aspect ratio. You can't have both all the video in view and have no white space. One or the other! I suspect you are more concerned to have the entire viewport filled than whether the entire video frame can be seen but please confirm this is the case.

Comment: @AHaworth, ah thanks for the explanation! I did not know I can't have both. In that case, I care more about having the entire viewport filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different viewports will have differing aspect ratios and so the video will not always fit exactly inside without some space at the top/bottom or the sides.

As it is  more important in this case to have the video filling the whole screen, this snippet illustrates using CSS `object-fit: cover` on the video element with the dimensions set to the whole viewport.

```css
video {
  z-index: -1000;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.showcase {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="showcase">
  <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" muted loop autoPlay></video>
</section>
```